# apache redirect - condition not matched correctly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following simple rewrite-statement and conditions in my virtualhost section of Apache (2.2) config

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]{2,})$ /bootstrap.php?url=$1
```

All requests are nicely redirected to the bootstrap.php, execpt if the file exists. That works fine. However, if a directory exists, I'd expect Apache to run the DirectoryIndex for that directory, or show the contents of the directory (whatever setting I choose), but Apache directs the request to the bootstrap.php too. It seems that the first rewriteCond is somehow not correct. What am I doing wrong?

When doing a debug, and trying to load "localhost/img" (which exists) I get the following output

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /img/
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (3) applying pattern '^([^\.]{2,})$' to uri '/img/'
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/img/' pattern='!-d' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/img/' pattern='!-f' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (2) rewrite '/img/' -> '/bootstrap.php?url=/img/'
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (3) split uri=/bootstrap.php?url=/img/ -> uri=/bootstrap.php, args=url=/img/
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (2) local path result: /bootstrap.php
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (2) prefixed with document_root to C:/webroot/zippyshoot/bootstrap.php
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:18:14 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#14442c0/initial] (1) go-ahead with C:/webroot/zippyshoot/bootstrap.php [OK]
```

Works fine when loading localhost/img/logo.png. Output of the debug log is then

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:27:56 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#237d978/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /img/logo.png
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:27:56 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#237d978/initial] (3) applying pattern '^([^\.]{2,})$' to uri '/img/logo.png'
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2013:20:27:56 +0100] [localhost/sid#4cd5a8][rid#237d978/initial] (1) pass through /img/logo.png
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ¿What happens when the file does not exist? Example: `localhost/img/test.test`? As far as I can see, the condition is not matched, the rule is not applied and the "not found" error should be generated. If so, the rule is skipped when the request is a file and it is not relevant if exists or not.

Comment: when the file does not exist, I get an error saying "the file does not exist on the server'. So the rewrite rule is not applied in that case.

Comment: So, `All requests are nicely redirected to the bootstrap.php, execpt if the file exists` is not accurate. The fact is the rule is applied only for directories. To be more precise: Only for strings without a period `.`. That's the reason why they are always passed to `bootstrap.php` as a parameter. It is not relevant if they exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the question in this post
http://amandine.aupetit.info/135/apache2-mod_rewrite/

As from Apache 2.2, the rewriteCond is changed. The correct way to write them is now

```
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```